# G Suite and Search Console — How to confirm the rights to the domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-search-console

When I registered G Suite, I confirmed the rights to the domain (DNS, TXT).

Now I want to add the site to the Search Console. That is, I again need to confirm the rights to the domain (DNS, TXT).

But I can’t do this, since only one TXT record can be created.

All this I do under one Google account.

Tell me, please, what should I do? After all, if I delete the old TXT record from G Suite, then over time the rights for it for the domain will fall off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My GSuite domain is via domaindiscount24 and that lets me add more TXT records.

Thought I'd post a screenshot if it helps.

[image]